# QWidget based class slot in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using Qt 4.7.3 and trying to solve the following problem.

I have a QML view with a QWidget based item on it ( I register it by calling qmlRegisterType("custom_qml_components", 1, 0, "Graphics");
). So far so good, this element is displayed in the window. But now, I want to use it's slot which should take QVector as a parameter.

What is the right way to connect such a slot to my signal?

As a first solution inside my mind I tried the following approach :
1. Declare  Q_PROPERTY( QVector dataFrame WRITE displayFrame ) for GraphicWidgetProxy class.
2. Declare the following slot inside QML file :

```
   function displayDataSlot ( dataBlock )
   {
      graph1.dataFrame = dataBlock;
   }
```

where

Graphics
  {
     id: graph1
     anchors.top: parent.top
     anchors.left: parent.left
     width: parent.width
     height: parent.height
  }

But unfortunately the connection like :

```
QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( displayDataSignal(QVector<float>) ), 
characteristicsViewObject, SLOT( displayDataSlot(QVector<float>) ) );
```

doesn't work...

Any ideas would be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance,
BR,
Dmitry

Comment: It not clear to me do you try to call a c++ slot or connect a QML slot to a c++ signal here? Usually you can just invoke the slot in the c++ class, so there is no need to do a permanent connection in most cases.

Note: I am not sure you can use QVector as a dynamic property, QList should work though. Maybe try your program with a simpler property first so you know it is no a problem with the data type.

Comment: The problem is caused by a fact that we could only use QString or QVariant for communication between c++ and QML.

The solution I've found is to use QVariant Property in QML. Then to form an array of floats I use QList<QVariant> and then wrap this variable to QVariant before emitting a signal.

Comment: may be a restriction of the QML to c++ data conversion, see here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html at least for the latest version you can use QList<qreal> which should be QList<double> (but not float on desktop machines? weird). Edit: tested it myself QList<qreal> works, but QList<float> does NOT.